Probability Problem Involving Dice Rolls: Conditional Probabilities of Events A and B
Throw red and blue dice, event A is "the number of blue dice points is 4 or 6", event B is "the sum of the two dice points is greater than 8", then P(B|A)=_____, P(A|B)=_____.
My method is as follows:
a = Tuples[{{4, 6}, Range[6]}]
b = Select[Tuples[{Range[6], Range[6]}], Total@# > 8 &]
ab = Intersection[a, b]
p1 = Length@ab/Length@a
p2 = Length@ab/Length@b

Are there other methods to solve this problem?

We can just naively use Mathematica's built-in Conditioned without putting a lot of thought into the problem itself:
diceDist = DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}];
eventA =  blue == 4 || blue == 6;
eventB = red + blue > 8;


(* P(B|A) *)
Probability[
 Conditioned[eventB, eventA], {red \[Distributed] diceDist, 
  blue \[Distributed] diceDist}]

(* P(A|B) *)
Probability[
 Conditioned[eventA, eventB], {red \[Distributed] diceDist, 
  blue \[Distributed] diceDist}]



1/2


3/5

